# Allow only unique combination of values for a composite primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I created the following table called `books`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books` (
`id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I created another tablet called `compare` to compare any 2 books from the `books` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `compare` (
`id_1` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`id_2` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_1`,`id_2`),
FOREIGN KEY (`id_1`) REFERENCES books(`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`id_2`) REFERENCES books(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The previous works as expected but I need to force MYSQL to allow ONLY unique combination of values in the `compare` table.

For example if I have the following row in `compare` table:

```
id_1 | id_2
------------
  1  |  2
```

I want to force MYSQL to NOT allow me to insert the following row:

```
id_1 | id_2
------------
 2  |  1
```

So I want MYSQL to allow only either `1,2` or `2,1` NOT both.

Comment: What you are looking for is to have your key defined as `UNIQUE`. Check this article: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html.

Comment: A primary key is actually a unique one

Comment: If MySQL supported `CHECK` constraints and it was acceptable to your users, insisting that `id_1` is less than `id_2` would be the standard way to go.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever if it's for checking, I can easily check if the row exists before inserting but I want to know if there is a standard MYSQL way to achieve what I need when creating the table

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted at DBA.SE (where it has an answer): https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204780/allow-only-unique-combination-of-values-for-a-composite-primary-key Please, one question, in one site, is enough.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ The answer on DBA.SE is for MariaDB only. This question (and the answers so far) are for MySQL.

Comment: @Vatev the two questions were posted by the same user, with 30 min difference. Both questions were tagged with mysql only originally. I think it's fair to assume that it's the same issue. Cross posting only adds more work, for people who answer or moderate.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ yes. I suppose they will get merged anyway when it's transferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way would be to swap the values in a before-insert trigger to make sure id_1 < id_2:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `compare_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `compare` FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
      DECLARE t BIGINT;
        IF(NEW.id_1 > NEW.id_2) THEN
            SET t = NEW.id_1;
            SET NEW.id_1 = NEW.id_2;
            SET NEW.id_2 = t;        
        END IF;
    END
```

This will allow you to use the key to make the pairs unique.

Comment: I like this trigger a bit better than the other one, as it has no subqueries and the unique part is let to be enforced by a UNIQE constraint.

Comment: This version will change the order of the ids.  That might not be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL (at least prior to version 8), you need to do this using a trigger if you want the database to enforce the constraint.

```
delimiter $$

create trigger compare_insert_trigger before insert on compare
for each row
begin
    if (exists (select 1
                from compare c
                where c.id2 = new.id1 and c.id1 = new.id2
               )
       ) then
        signal sqlsate '45000'
        set message_text = 'Book pair already exists in compare';
    end if;
end;$$

delimiter ;
```

Of course, you still need the unique constraint.

Comment: That's not strictly true. You don't **need** a trigger, as there are other ways to enforce similar constraints.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ . . . Please add an answer if you have another method not using a trigger in MySQL prior to version 8.

Comment: I've already added an answer in the cross-posting at DBA.SE, using `CHECK` constraints, as he commented that he uses MariaDB 10.2 and not vanilla MySQL.

Comment: Regarding other ways, see my answer here (the section "emulating arbitrary CHECK constraints in MySQL"): https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/check-constraint-does-not-work/22019#22019